# Print 5 letter or numbers to fit in cells

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would to make a table. The cells have a fixed size.

How can I cut the letters or numbers so that they fit in the cells? Is there a possibility (e.g. limit string or int)?

It should run automatically automated and work for all sorts of scenarios.
This is my Code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import table


def main():
    data_frame = pd.read_excel('C:/test/TestArrays.xlsx')

    with PdfPages('multipage.pdf') as pdf:
        columns_per_page = 10
        for page_no, start_column in enumerate(
        range(0, data_frame.shape[1], columns_per_page), 1
    ):
        sub_frame = data_frame.iloc[
            0:15, start_column:start_column + columns_per_page
        ]
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 1))
        fig.suptitle('1.Excel-Daten-Seite-{}'.format(page_no), fontsize=15)
        ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
        ax.set_frame_on(False)
        a_table = table(ax, sub_frame, colWidths=[0.2] * sub_frame.shape[1])
        a_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
        a_table.set_fontsize(15)
        a_table.scale(1.5, 1.5)
        cells = a_table.get_celld()
        for cell in (cells[0, i] for i in range(sub_frame.shape[1])):
            cell.set_fontsize(13)
            cell.set_color('grey')
        pdf.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

[image]

Comment: If `s="mylongstring"`, you can limit the string to 5 characters via `s[:min(len(s),5)]`. The same does not work with integers in general, i.e. if your integer is `123456` and you want to cut it to 5 places, it gets completely wrong (`12345`). In that sense you need to define what you would like to happen in such case.

Comment: `s[:min(len(s), 5)]` behaves the same way as `s[:5]`, even if the string is shorter than 5 characters.

Comment: No, thats exactly what I want. Olny the first 5 numbers should be displayed. I need that for an overview.

Comment: And how does it work for at 100 columns or raws?

Comment: `"{:.5}".format(str(val))` might work better for you depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: How could it be integrated intio into my code? Here is a picture.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with excel, or with the modules that you are using. But, as far as I understand. You want to cut off the text if it is greater than a specific amount of letters. For this, you can use `list[:n]`. Basically what this does is returns `n` number of elements from a list. But, you have a string, so...

```
maxlen = 5                         #the maximum number of characters you want the string to have
def trunc(text):
    global maxlen
    thelist = [i for i in text]    #converts the text string into a list
    trunclist = thelist[:maxlen]   #truncates the list
    trunctext = ''.join(trunclist) #converts it back into a string
    return trunctext               #returns truncated text
```

So, wherever you want to display text `foo`, just use `trunc(foo)`

(BTW, just make sure that the input is a string)

**EDIT:**
I just saw that the truncating command can be used in strings as well, so...

```
 maxlen = 5                         #the maximum number of characters you want the string to have
 def trunc(text):
     return text[:maxlen]               #returns truncated text
```